# Not sorting a bibtex for a single page

Tags: bibtex, sorting

I use `unsrt` style for my BibTeX bibliography and everything is fine. It sorts the entries according to the hierarchy in which I refer to them. However, for one page (which is the abstract of my work) I don't want the entries to be counted. For instance, in that page I reference to a paper I mentioned in chapter 7 which is [67] and then another one from chapter 9 which is [89]. But as soon as I cite them in the preface, they become [1] and [2]

Comment: In general the abstract is something that should be able to stand on its own separate from the work, so it should not contain reference numbers.

Comment: Abstracts should NOT contain any citation or reference.

Answer (score 3):

In general the abstract is something that should be able to stand on its own separate from the work, so it should not contain reference numbers.  However, if you really need this then for standard documents you turn off the writing of the `\ciation` command by issuing `\@fielswfalse` (suitably surrounded by `\makeatletter...\maketother`):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  \makeatletter\@fileswfalse\makeatother
  My abstract has references~\cite{inbook-minimal}.
\end{abstract}

A reference in the main text~\cite{article-minimal}.

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I concur with Andrew Swann's comment. If possible, no citation should be made in the abstract or, if they are, a generic mention of the authors should suffice.

If you want to have citations in the abstract and that they don't count for `unsrt`, here'a a couple of patches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\write@citation}{\string\citation}
\newcommand{\write@nocitation}{\string\@gobble}
\patchcmd\@citex{\string\citation}{\perhaps@write@citation}{}{}
\patchcmd\nocite{\string\citation}{\perhaps@write@citation}{}{}
\newcommand{\ignorecite}{\global\let\perhaps@write@citation\write@nocitation}
\newcommand{\dontignorecite}{\global\let\perhaps@write@citation\write@citation}
\dontignorecite % initialize to normal
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{A paper}
\author{A. Uthor}

\maketitle

\ignorecite

\begin{abstract}
In the abstract we cite \cite{article-minimal} and \cite{book-minimal}
\end{abstract}

\dontignorecite

\section{A section}

Here we cite \cite{mastersthesis-minimal}, then \cite{phdthesis-minimal}
and finally \cite{book-minimal} and \cite{article-minimal}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{xampl} % should be in every TeX distribution

\end{document}
```

You write `\ignorecite` at the start of the region where `\cite` commands should not count for the order of appearance and `\dontignorecite` when this region ends.

The patch are intended to make LaTeX write `\@gobble{<key>}` in the `.aux` file instead of `\citation{<key>}` in the region.

[image]